# Google Sheets: How to get the last non-zero and non-empty value in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

Say Column A has the following values in 7 rows:

2
[blank]
0
-0.3
0
[blank]
0

How can I get the last value in the range (7 rows) which is not empty/blank, and not zero? Therefore in this case, the correct answer would be -0.3.

Answer (score 12):

`=INDEX(A:A, MAX(FILTER(ROW(A:A),NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),A:A>0)), 0)`

Ripped off of this answer:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/kgDmjZ-zhMY

Comment: Nice. It wasn't working for me initially because I wanted to return the value in the same column.  Here's a formula that should work even in the same column: `=INDEX(A:A, MAX(FILTER(ROW(A2:A),NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)),A2:A<>0)), 0)`